# Changing dtype object to int

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a column named property size in a dataset I'm working on. The values are in m^2.This is an example of a value in the column (100m^2).

How can I change the values in this column from dtype object to int. So I basically want to remove the m^2 from the values.

Comment: strip the `m^2` from the string, convert to an `int`  So remove the last three characters from the string . . . `df['some_col_name'] = df['some_col_name'].str[:-3].astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same unit, you can just use string slicing to cut it off:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["1m^2", "20m^2"], columns=["area"])

df["area"] = df["area"].str[:-3].astype(int)
```

results in:

```
   area
0     1
1    20
```